# Can I define a single model but have variations of it with some fields required?

Tags: typescript

For our API you might create an Order. The order has the exact same model for various endpoints however what changes is the fields that are required.

POST - a few fields are required

PATCH - all fields are optional

PUT - all fields are required

Can I model this in typescript so I only have a single model to maintain and then provide some information on the API calls to denote the required fields?

Comment: Check `Partial<T>` at https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

Comment: It looks like that along with `Required<T>` would satisfy two of my cases (all required or all optional) I'm hoping there's something that can give me a bit more granular control where I define between none and all fields that are required. My example was simple with just three but there may be many more models where the only difference is which fields are required

Comment: Ah never mind I figured out a way in that same link you sent there's an example for `PartialWithNewMember`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this specifically with [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types), in either the make-required or make-optional directions (thanks to support added in TS2.8 for [removing modifiers in mapped types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#improved-control-over-mapped-type-modifiers)).  Here's how I'd do it without knowing specifically about the types or keys you'd like to manipulate:

```
// Require<T, K> takes an object type T and a set of its keys K
// and produces a new type identical to T except that the properties at keys K
// are now required.  If K is left out, Require<T> behaves like Required<T>.
type Require<T, K extends keyof T = keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>> &
  Required<Pick<T, K>> extends infer U
  ? { [P in keyof U]: U[P] }
  : never;

// Optionalize<T, K> takes an object type T and a set of its keys K
// and produces a new type identical to T except that the properties at keys K
// are now optional.  If K is left out, Optionalize<T> behaves like Partial<T>.
type Optionalize<T, K extends keyof T = keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>> &
  Partial<Pick<T, K>> extends infer U
  ? { [P in keyof U]: U[P] }
  : never;
```

Those are basically mirror images of each other... they use a bunch of built-in mapped type like `Pick`, `Partial`, and `Required`, as well as some custom and built-in [conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#conditional-types) like `Exclude`.  The idea is that you split up the properties of `T` into those with keys in `K` and those without.  You modify the ones in `K`, leave the other ones alone, and build a new type with all the properties put back together.  Let's test it:

```
// Tests
interface AnInterface {
  req1: string;
  readonly req2: number;
  readonly opt1?: boolean;
  opt2?: object;
}

type SomeRequired = Require<AnInterface, "req1" | "opt1">;
// type SomeRequired = {
//   readonly req2: number;
//   opt2?: object | undefined;
//   req1: string; // was already required, still is
//   readonly opt1: boolean; // now required
// }

type SomeOptional = Optionalize<AnInterface, "req1" | "opt1">;
// type SomeOptional = {
//   readonly req2: number;
//   opt2?: object | undefined;
//   req1?: string | undefined; // now optional
//   readonly opt1?: boolean | undefined; // was already optional, still is
// }
```

Those look good to me.  Of course if you don't need a general-purpose solution like this you can perform the same or similar type mapping with your specific object types and key names.  It's up to you.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://typescript-play.js.org/#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-scFXPjMfn8AcDQRDoXCEZnFqiMUCsbj8UqiaSyeo0BR5CpftNEFIiPpQABBai5awAldryGg1IARgx5AIiF+AHNSTlkEQhLT7JxQKkAEwE2AAWwaJMPkHvj7PvaR5ghiDB0HQJQ0De9BeK+oFciw7CknicbmAAynQn6QI8PSgCsuGoJu25LnukBYAARMeFGgAAPqAFHARRuCkuogwYVhOFdE8+FQuSt7-g+1BPi+MDvokX4-qxYA5Pa8EYowSEcPRsDCKUvwZNJOSidAJ5iOeV7EqA6jGEQHL2HeQjPqkoxCFgZ7wPYjjwOQ-GiQBwlAV4engZB-7UEZ6i2jptnkqh7F8Jh2EJo6jgrDFSaBsRO7Lqu5EMdRdEMUxLHkhFoBRZACVaisB7qAJHkiW+H7fgCWmyXBCGKTyWWqZYUgaUI9U6SBp4GdQl6tWpHVGF1xlgMF9qJg4bmWYBsEEL1wYQVBtAqcNnWBWApnmZZXl+g49k2E5RRhSoQA)

Comment: Beautiful! Both of these should make make their way into typescript defaults